# Finding the correct screen replacement for a netbook

Tags: laptop, display, netbook

I have to change my netbook's screen. It's 13" (or 13.3") diagonal-wise with a matte/non-glossy/unpolished LED display.

**What do I have to be careful for when buying a new screen?**

Is this a pretty generic part in a laptop or is it specific? My netbook is a no-brand netbook so it is bit difficult to find information about its component.

Comment: It would probably be cheaper to buy a new netbook. Especially if it's no-brand it couldn't have been too expensive. Cost of buying a new screen, hassle, and risk is all outweighed by just getting a new one.

Comment: I am aware of the alternative but I do not want to throw and replace, that is too easy. Plus my current netbook as a few nice stickers on it and I want to keep them.

Comment: Are you able to give us the make and model? Generic machines like this tend to use generic components, another make of laptop may have the same screen and be easier to locate.

Comment: It's a M13A (SU2300 but that's just the processor's model). It is actually from a mass manufacturer who sells to re-seller.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed a few laptop screens and if the laptop is recent enough, it should have a standard screen with a 30-pin eDP connector. I have also seen a wider 40-pin connector and some older laptops might have something like LVDS. Be sure to disassemble yours first and check the mounts, the connector location and count its pins. The manufacturer or even the resolution do not matter. I have successfully replaced WXGA (1366×768) screens with full HD (1920×1080) and vice versa.

Comment: That's what I thought. I am going to go ahead and buy the standard-est same-size screen and just see what happens.